# Who decided that computers must be 32-bits? Why not 31-bits, or 42-bits?

Tags: memory, computer-science, bit

I'm just wondering what's special with 32 and 64 that they became the chosen "bit-size"? You know I hear these things like 32-bit. I can't get what's special with these numbers? What if I want to build a PC that's 57-bits??

Comment: Not an answer, but there's a bit to this. There have been 12-bit, 36-bit, and 48-bit architectures. Depending on how you define it, I've owned a computer with a 24-bit architecture.

Comment: I still don't get... so it was IBM who decided all this?? @JakeGould

Comment: hey why are people voting off my question, is it really so stupid to ask this kind of question? for me it makes sense you know...

Comment: I learned to program on a system with a 60-bit architecture.

Answer (score 2):

> You know I hear these things like 32-bit. I can't get what's special
>   with these numbers? What if I want to build a PC that's 57-bits??

32 and 64 are multiples of 8. And to my knowledge this all has roots in [Industry Standard Architecture (ISA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture). Which then leads to the [Extended Industry Standard Architecture (EISA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Industry_Standard_Architecture).

**Which boils down to this:** It’s the same reason there are light bulb socket standards & nut/bolt standards. If you want to build a “`57-bit`” system, good luck with that. You would have to build a machine from the literal ground up based on a 57-bit standard which you will have to come up with. The original IBM PC architecture was built around the Intel 8088 chip which itself was based on an 8-bit standard. And since that architecture was based on an open standard—which happened to be 8-bit—manufactures followed that standard & even developed their own to assure interoperability.

Comment: now this is getting somewhere... im reading the links! points for you

Comment: This neglects the fact that PDP-11's predated ISA by a considerable time, and that there were other (non-Intel) 8 / 16 / 32-bit microprocessors before ISA hit the streets (as it were).  IMO, ISA was a reaction to the trend in microprocessor architectures ... not the other way around.